# How to Add Multiple CSS Files to a Skin?

Tags: css, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, skinning

I'm using multiple CSS files in my ADF Fusion Web Application which I want to be a part of the "skyros" skin. I got some idea by following **[this](http://skinningadf.blogspot.in/2015/04/configuring-custom-skin-in-adf.html)** article. So I was wondering if I include multiple CSS files in my `trinidad-skins.xml` file.

At present, this is what I have:

```
// trinidad-skins.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<skins xmlns="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin">
    <skin>
        <id>custom.desktop</id>
        <family>myCSS</family>
        <extends>skyros-v1.desktop</extends>
        <style-sheet-name>css/style.css</style-sheet-name>
    </skin>
</skins>



// trinidad-config.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<trinidad-config xmlns="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/config">
  <skin-family>myCSS</skin-family>
  <skin-version>v1</skin-version>
</trinidad-config>
```

This is what is expected:

```
//trinidad-skins.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<skins xmlns="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/skin">
    <skin>
        <id>custom.desktop</id>
        <family>myCSS</family>
        <extends>skyros-v1.desktop</extends>
        <style-sheet-name>css/style.css</style-sheet-name>
        <style-sheet-name>css/style2.css</style-sheet-name>
    </skin>
</skins>
```

> My jDeveloper version is 11g (11.1.1.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using an import in your CSS so you have one CSS import the other - @import url("base.css");

Comment: Yes I did. But unfortunately, that didn't seem to work